# Format cell file .xls made by php

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I have a MySQL database where I have a table with several columns and records.

I have made a .php script can made a file .xls with all records can i have in my table.

Everything works fine but the problem occurs when i find an id like this '36E49'.Microsoft Excel format the cell that contains the value '36E49' in scientific and the value become '3,6E+50'.

Example of my code:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel; name='excel'");
header("Content-Disposition: filename=$filename");  
?>

<table width="1702" border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<tr>
 <td style="background-color: #F0F0F0; text-align: center;" width="160"><b><u>ID</u></b></td>
 <td style="background-color: #F0F0F0; text-align: center;" width="170"><b><u>Description</u></b></td>
</tr>

<?php
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM .............."); 
while($result = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
  $id1 = $result['id1'];
  $id2 = $result['id2'];
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>$id1</td>";
  echo "<td>$id2</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Thanks!

***I 've solved the problem***

For solve my problem i had use the fuction ="value"

Example:

```
<?php
echo "<td>=\"$id1\"</td>";
?>
```

Or if you are not in php:

```
<td><?php echo "=\"$id\""; ?></td>
```

Comment: To be honest, I'm shocked that this works at all. I had no idea you could spit out an HTML table and have Excel treat it as a spreadsheet. To achieve proper types, you'll need to use a library such as PHPExcel.

Comment: I 've solved the problem . Thanks anyway

Comment: Good stuff. Make sure you post the answer yourself and mark it as the accepted answer. I'd be interested in how you got around it.

Comment: Mark my answers. Thank!

Comment: lol, you'll need to mark your own. Just a click the checkmark beside your answer

Comment: I can't mark my answer

Comment: Is there not a tick next you your answer (below the up/down)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I 've solved the problem***

For solve my problem i had use the fuction ="value"

Example:

```
<?php
echo "<td>=\"$id1\"</td>";
?>
```

Or if you are not in php:

```
<td><?php echo "=\"$id\""; ?></td>
```